# Phonegap camera function

Tags: cordova

I know there are many questions here about Phonegap and using the camera function. 
I tried to solve the problem, but still have no solution.

Device is Nexus 7, the camera won´t start after building the app.
Here is the code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="PhoneGap.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// PhoneGap is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
  // console.log(imageData);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
  // console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-
encoded string  
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: 
true }); 
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
```

---

tried it with a samsung galaxy s2 ... once again nothing happened!
i don´t know the problem!?
here is the code:

**androidmainfest.xml permissions:**

```xml
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

**and here the code from the html file:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// PhoneGap is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
  // console.log(imageData);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
  // console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64- 
encoded string  
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: 
true }); 
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo 
Album</button><br>
<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
<img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide options as mentioned in the documentation. Example:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
 });
```

Rereference:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture

Comment: I added this line but it didn´t work. So do i have to edit the manifest.xml in case of permissions?

Comment: You need write_external_storage and camera permission.

Comment: but when building the app with the online service there´s no chance to edit the mainfest.xml?

Comment: You can specify the permission in config.xml or just build it yourself.

Comment: it doesn´t work ... installed eclipse, the phonegap plugin and all the other android things which are necessary ... when i call the apk-file the app is running, but when i push the button the camera does not start ... permissions are specified in the androidManifest.xml

Comment: Make sure your cordova.js or phonegap.js is called what you put in the src. In your case, make sure it is really called PhoneGap.js or just copy paste the example from the doc site. It does work.

Comment: it´s the code from the website ... the cordova-2.5.0.js is in the root directory ... --> src="cordova-2.5.0.js" when clicking the buttons there is nothing ...

Comment: Do you see in the log if you have javascript errors? The code you gave  says you use PhoneGap.js. Do you use other code now?

Comment: ok, sorry - i use the code from the doc site and the framework is  cordova-2.5.0.js

Comment: Do you see in the log if you have javascript errors?  Or even Java errors in the logcat? Please change the code to reflect the new code you tested.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! i think here´s the problem ... 

is it right ... ?

https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/90

Comment: :) Maybe that's it. Try with other device to make sure. If so, you should post there saying that you have the same issue so the devs know.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works. Don´t know the problem, but it works.
Here´s the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function capturePhoto(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,null,{sourceType:1,quality:60});
}

function uploadPhoto(data){
    // this is where you would send the image file to server
    //output image to screen
        cameraPic.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
    }

navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName]);

navigator.notification.alert(
        'Your Photo has been uploaded', // message
        okay,                           // callback
        'Photo Uploaded',               // title
        'OK'                            // buttonName
    );

function uploadPhoto(data){
    // this is where you would send the image file to server
        cameraPic.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
        // Successful upload to the server
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'Your Photo has been uploaded',  // message
            okay,                           // callback
            'Photo Uploaded',              // title
            'OK'                          // buttonName
        );
        // upload has failed Fail
        /*
        if (failedToUpload){
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'Your Photo has failed to upload',
            failedDismissed,
            'Photo Not Uploaded',
            'OK'
            );
        }
        */
    }
    function okay(){
        // Do something
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="camera">
    <button class="camera-control" onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button>
    <div style="text-align:center;margin:20px;">
        <img id="cameraPic" src="" style="width:auto;height:120px;"></img>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your mobile memory is not enough,This problem isn't actually about Phonegap. It's a common issue on native android apps too.It occurs because when the camera is triggered, the android activity goes background (onStop state), waiting for the camera to take the picture. Then the GC comes and kills the activity to free memory before the conclusion of camera action, and when the camera is done your activity has already died. That is why the app is restarted.

Here is my suggests

1 .Replace cramer plugin, avoid using custom plug-ins start garbage collection, (http://code.google.com/p/foreground-camera-plugin/, http://code.google.com/p/foreground-gallery- plugin /)
2. Detects memory if insufficient to kill other processes, active release memory
3. Improve their survival, try to avoid the release of memory in the system selected.

```
    private void clearMemory(boolean killAll)
{
    mklog("当前系统可用内存大小是：" + getAvailMemory(getApplicationContext()));
    ActivityManager activityManger = (ActivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list = activityManger
            .getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (list != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo apinfo = list.get(i);

            System.out.println("pid            " + apinfo.pid);
            System.out.println("processName              "
                    + apinfo.processName);
            System.out
                    .println("importance            " + apinfo.importance);
            String[] pkgList = apinfo.pkgList;

            if (apinfo.importance >= ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND
                    || (killAll && apinfo.importance >= ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_SERVICE))
            {
                // Process.killProcess(apinfo.pid);
                for (int j = 0; j < pkgList.length; j++)
                {
                    activityManger.killBackgroundProcesses(pkgList[j]);
                    mklog("准备杀死进程：" + pkgList[j]);
                }
            }

        }

    mklog("清理之后 当前系统可用内存大小是：" + getAvailMemory(getApplicationContext()));
}

private long getAvailMemory(Context context)
{
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
    am.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    return mi.availMem / (1024 * 1024);
}   
      public void mklog(String contentString)
{
    Log.i("Web Console", contentString);
}
```